# Mat-table renders rows but not data

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am using Angular 5 & Material mat-table in my project.

In my component file, I use observable to retrieve data from the service and bind it to a variable on the component. Mat-table displays rows but it does not print data. I tried ngFor and it seems to work. No errors in console. Any ideas why the table is not displayin data?

TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

import { NotificationService } from './../../core/services/notification.service';
import { OperationConfiguration } from './../../core/models/operationConfiguration';
import { ProgressBarService } from '../../core/services/progress-bar.service';
import { OperationConfigurationService } from '../../core/services/operation-configuration.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-operation-configuration-list',
  templateUrl: './operation-configuration-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./operation-configuration-list.component.css']
})
export class OperationConfigurationListComponent implements OnInit {

  operationConfigurations: OperationConfiguration[];
  columnsToDisplay: ['id', 'columnName', 'hidden'];

  constructor(private progressBarService: ProgressBarService,
    private notificationService: NotificationService,
    private configurationService: OperationConfigurationService) {
    this.progressBarService.show();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadOperationConfigurations();
  }

  private loadOperationConfigurations(): void {

    this.configurationService.getAll(null)
      .subscribe(
        results => {
          this.operationConfigurations = results;
          this.progressBarService.hide();
        },
        error => {
          if (error.statusText === 'Unknown Error') {
            this.notificationService.openSnackBar('An error occurred, please try again later.');
          } else {
            this.notificationService.openSnackBar(error.error);
          }
          this.progressBarService.hide();
        }
      );
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<!-- THIS WORKS -->
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let c of operationConfigurations">
    {{ c.id }}
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- THIS DOES NOT WORK -->
<mat-table [dataSource]="operationConfigurations">

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let rowData; columns: columnsToDisplay"></mat-row>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> # </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let column">
      {{column.id}}
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="columnName">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Column </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let column">
      {{column.columnName}}
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="hidden">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Visibility </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let column">
      {{column.hidden}}
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

</mat-table>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The culprit appears to be the way I declared `columnsToDisplay`

I changed the following line:

`columnsToDisplay: ['id', 'columnName', 'hidden'];`

to

`columnsToDisplay = ['id', 'columnName', 'hidden'];`

and the problem is solved.

Still learning typescript!

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I did the same exact thing and could not see it.

Comment: This is the second time I've had this issue and spent an embarrassing amount of time hunting down why my ng-containers were empty. This is also the second time this post pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! Man, this had me stumped for ages! A typo for sure, but it took your comment for me to double-check and spot it.

Answer (score 1):

Using angular material 6 and running into the same issue. I am using = not : but still doesn't show data.

```
columns: Column[] = new CommentColumns().columns;
displayedColumns = [...this.columns.map(x => x.columnDef)];
```

However, data shows up when I change `<mat-table>` to `<table mat-table>` and `<mat-row>` to `<tr mat-row>`.

Comment: This should probably be made a comment rather than an answer once you have enough reputation to do so.